# How to map different types of objects in JSONArray-to-List<MyObject> using Jackson?

Tags: java, jackson

I have a JSONObject something like:

```
  {
   "name": "John",
   "details": [
      [
       "phone",
       123456789
      ],
      [
       "address",
       "abcdef"
      ]
   ]
}
```

I am trying to map the above jSON to the following object:

```
 @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
 public class Employee{
       String name;
       List<List<DetailItem>> details;


       public String getName() {
       return name;
       }
       public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
       }
       public List<List<DetailItem>> getDetails() {
      return details;
       }
       public void setDetails(List<List<DetailItem>> details) {
      this.details = details;
       }

    }


     @JsonSubTypes({
       @JsonSubTypes.Type(value=String.class),
       @JsonSubTypes.Type(value=Integer.class)
       })
    public class DetailItem{

    }
```

mapping using:

```
     ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
     mapper.readValue(instream, Employee.class)
```

Exception:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, DetailItem] from String value; no single-String constructor/factory method (through reference chain: Employe["details"])
```

I am trying to do polymorphic deserialization as `DetailItem` is either `String` or `Integer`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is simply ***not*** how polymorphic deserialization works! You are ignoring the very definition of what polymorphism is and trying to magically create relationships between classes that *are not related*. Even though its not explicitly enforced, the type annotated with `@JsonSubTypes` should be a parent class to each of the defined `@Type`s.

```
@JsonSubTypes({
    @Type(value=String.class), // String is not a subclass of DetailItem!
    @Type(value=Integer.class) // Integer is not a subclass of DetailItem!
})
public class DetailItem{
}
```

The root problem is the very shoddily designed JSON input. I won't even ask why each of the `detail` properties has been denormalized and stored into separate arrays, but I would **strongly** recommend fixing the format to be something more sensible. For example:

```
{
    "name": "John",
    "details": {
        "phone" : 123456789,
        "address" : "abcedf",
    }
}
```

The above could be trivially deserialized into the following object:

```
class Employee {
    private Sting name;
    private Map<String, Object> details;

    // constructor, getters/setters
}
```

If you are stuck with the current format then either change your `List<List<DetailItem>>` to `List<List<Object>>`, or [implement a custom deserializer](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHowToCustomDeserializers).

Comment: I don't have control over what server returns. So for the time being `List<List<Object>>` works. Thanks